# 'Other than she' v. 'other than her'

Tags: grammar

Let me ask another silly question. Does 'other than' take the subjective, or objective case, or does it depend? In short, is 'other than she/he etc.' grammatical (or can it be)?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30930/than-her-versus-than-she

Comment: @KateBunting In other words, 'other than she' is pedantically correct, while 'other than her' is informally inaccurate, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["than her" versus "than she"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30930/than-her-versus-than-she)

Answer (score 0):

"No one knew the answer other than he" is grammatically correct.

"***He knew the answer***" is correct, and therefore using "***he***" in the first expression you give here is correct too ("... ***other than he***").

Comment: Your answer is confusing and lacks research. Which first sentence?