# Why should the word "I" be replaced with "me" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, comparative-constructions, personal-pronouns

Question is Identify grammatical errors in this sentence.

Sentence:

> Though I am elder than my Brother by five years, he is more successful
>   in life than me.

My Lecture told me word **than** should be replace with word **to** & also word **me** should replaced with word **I**.

Which is really made confused, Actually word **than me** make more sense to say than word **than I**.

Comment: There are two "than"s in the sentence. I assume your instructor wanted the first one to be replaced with "to", but I think you should make it clear by writing the instructor's preferred version of the sentence (I'm guessing it is 
"Though I am elder **to** my Brother by five years, he is more successful in life than **I**").

Comment: @sumelic Either that, or the OP has typoed _elder_ for _older._

Comment: @DhanrajKumar Do you know what an _objective pronoun_ is?

Comment: You would use "I" rather than "me" because there is an implied "am" there.  You haven't put the verb there, but it's impliedly there.  i.e. "he is more successful in life than I [am]."

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you!  By the way, I want to make certain to indicate that implying "am" here is perfectly acceptable.  It can be stated, but it is commonly implied in similar situations in English, both written and spoken.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie _Than_ has been a bone of contention for centuries. See Ben Kovitz's marvelous digression **[here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44188/37009)** Belief in the implied (or elided) _am_ indicates membership in the Conjunction cadre. As Ben says, we must take sides!